# PHP how to rotate all array elements

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array like...

```
Array ( [0] => 'Mon' [1] => 'Sun' [2] => 'Sat' [3] => 'Fri' [4] => 'Thu' [5] => 'Wed' [6] => 'Tue' )
```

I want it as follows...

```
Array ( [0] => 'Tue' [1] => 'Wed' [2] => 'Thu' [3] => 'Fri' [4] => 'Sat' [5] => 'Sun' [6] => 'Mon' )
```

Comment: array_reverse($array);

Comment: Yoy need to try out something and come back with any problem faced. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

```
$a= your array;
$y = array_reverse($a);
```

$y will return your expected output.Hope this will help you

Answer (score 0):

You should use [array_reverse()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reverse.php)

```
$arr = array(0 => 'Mon', 1 => 'Sun', '2' => 'Sat', 3 => 'Fri', 4 => 'Thu');
$newArr = array_reverse($arr);
print_r($newArr);
```

Output:

```
Array ( [0] => Thu [1] => Fri [2] => Sat [3] => Sun [4] => Mon )
```

Comment: Greate. Work for me !